# How to remove the title bar from the desktop flutter application? always leave the application in full screen mode

Tags: flutter, window, desktop

I have a parking payment project on a precise totem that does not let the user close the application, so I need the maximize, minimize and close buttons not to appear, an application made on a desktop flutter windows.

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397479/flutter-desktop-frameless-window-support. You'll need to change the window properties in native code.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71355167/12649675. It's uses one of the most actively maintained plugin to handle such situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Dart code. [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) helps it.

If you are using Windows, add this package to `pubspec.yaml` and add below code to the first part of `<project>/windows/runner/main.cpp`.

```
#include <bitsdojo_window_windows/bitsdojo_window_plugin.h>
auto bdw = bitsdojo_window_configure(BDW_CUSTOM_FRAME | BDW_HIDE_ON_STARTUP);
```

And add this code to `main.dart`.

```
doWhenWindowReady(() {
  appWindow.show();
});
```

You can also do more customizing with this package.