# How to Remove Title Bar from Flutter app built for windows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I've made a simple flutter app for windows, when I run it shows the default Titlebar that windows has. How can I remove it ??

Comment: As title bar do you mean where the cross, minimize, etc is situated?

Comment: Yes, i mean where the Close, Minimize, maximize buttons are situated

Answer (score 11):

Use this package [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) and do this.

Add this line to the top of the file:

```
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';
```

Then add this line of code(this function is not officially documented).

```
void main() async{
  runApp(const MyApp());
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async{
      await windowManager.setAsFrameless();
  });
}
```

You may alternatively want just to hide the titlebar but leave the buttons visible. This can be done as follows:

```
await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);
```

Answer (score 6):

Using this package [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) do the following:

Inside your application folder, go to `windows\runner\main.cpp` and add these two lines at the beginning of the file:

```
#include <bitsdojo_window_windows/bitsdojo_window_plugin.h>
auto bdw = bitsdojo_window_configure(BDW_CUSTOM_FRAME | BDW_HIDE_ON_STARTUP);
```

Now go to `lib\main.dart` and add this code in the main function right after `runApp(MyApp());` :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());

  // Add this code below

  doWhenWindowReady(() {
    appWindow.show();
  });
}
```

You can also customize the window with something like:

```
  doWhenWindowReady(() {
    final initialSize = Size(600, 450);
    appWindow.minSize = initialSize;
    appWindow.size = initialSize;
    appWindow.alignment = Alignment.center;
    appWindow.show();
  });
```

To implement your own title buttons and text, you can use these methods from the package:

```
appWindow.title(title);
appWindow.close();
appWindow.maximize();
appWindow.minimize();
```

You can also give the properties of the title bar to any widget (like dragging and double click for maximize) by wraping it inside `MoveWindow()` widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  WindowManager.instance.ensureInitialized();
  WindowManager.instance.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```