# flutter: how to hide the top bar of an app

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I hide the topbar of an app in flutter? I want to restrict users from closing the app.[image]

Comment: So, you don't want users to give the option to close the app? or is there any specific use-case you have in mind?

Comment: i do not want users to have the option to close the app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Remove Title Bar from Flutter app built for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852107/how-to-remove-title-bar-from-flutter-app-built-for-windows)

Comment: I got inspired by that post, but the right answer is a bit different now. I will post my solution here

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Add to dependencies  `window_manager: ^0.2.8`
2. Import in main.dart `import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';`
3. Place the following code

```
        runApp(App());
        windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async{
          await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);
        });
```